# How to feed camera's raw data directly to encoder in android NDK

Tags: android, android-ndk, android-mediacodec

I am working on native app (no Java API calls) on which I need to encode camera's live feed and dump it. And avoid any memcpy to encoder's input buffer.
Previously I was able to capture yuv data from camera using AImage reader, and save it , also able to encode it by passing saved yuv it to encoder's input buffer , But now want to avoid saving and then passing it to encoder.
Is there any way we can achieve this using only AMediacodec API available in android ndk .

Answer (score 1):

There is no guarantee that a built-in encoder will accept one of the image formats that you receive from the camera, but if it does, there is no need to 'save' the frame. The tricky part is that both camera and encoder work asynchronously, so the frames that you receive from AImageReader must be queued to be consumed by AMediaCodec. If you don't want to memcpy these threads to the queue, your camera may stumble when there are not free buffers,

But it may be easier and more efficient to wire the encoder to surface via [AMediaCodec_createInputSurface()](https://developer.android.com/ndk/reference/group/media#amediacodec_createinputsurface) instead of relying on buffers.

Comment: Hi Alex thank you for response I tried with  AMediaCodec_createInputSurface() API and passed  Native window owned by AImage reader (is it correct way) , but not sure about how its gonna feed camera feed to encoder can you provide any sample code for do it correctly . As on internet none info is available about this .

Comment: I must confess that I have never done this in C++, but the logic must be straightforward translation of the Java ways. The major caveat is that the NDK APIs require higher target platform (IIRC, API 26), while the Java API was introduced at API 24.